# 401 Authentication issue with Django using DRF and Django Rest Knox with correct credentials

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-rest-framework

I'm getting the error 401 when I try to log into my Django application after I tried to implement Django Rest Knox's Token Authentication.
[image]

I've only very slightly customized Django's Knox LoginView function, and am using a custom User model, which essentially uses organizations' emails in the "username" field.

My objectives are:

1. Multiple tokens per user (for multiple device support).
2. Token removal upon logout (security best practice).
3. Feature to remove all tokens (logout from all devices).
4. Secure token storage (encryption/decryption).
5. Token expiration.

However, I'm stuck at the authentication at the moment.

Django 4.2.3.
Django Rest Framework 3.14.0.
Django Rest Knox 4.2.0.

It's still not deployed, so it's in DEBUG mode, and I'm running the server in WSL in the localhost while I develop it.

*It just doesn't make any sense*. It says the credentials were not provided, but they quite clearly were there when I tested with Insomnia.

Relevant sections from my settings.py:

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'accounts',
    'knox',
    'rest_framework',
(..)
]

# AUTH USER
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.CustomUser'

# REST FRAMEWORK
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': ('knox.auth.TokenAuthentication',),
}

REST_KNOX = {
    'SECURE_HASH_ALGORITHM':'cryptography.hazmat.primitives.hashes.SHA512',
    'AUTH_TOKEN_CHARACTER_LENGTH': 64, # By default, it is set to 64 characters (this shouldn't need changing).
    'TOKEN_TTL': timedelta(hours=8), # The default is 10 hours i.e., timedelta(hours=10)).
    'USER_SERIALIZER': 'knox.serializers.UserSerializer',
    'TOKEN_LIMIT_PER_USER': None, # By default, this option is disabled and set to None -- thus no limit.
    'AUTO_REFRESH': False, # This defines if the token expiry time is extended by TOKEN_TTL each time the token is used.
    'EXPIRY_DATETIME_FORMAT': api_settings.DATETIME_FORMAT,
}

KNOX_TOKEN_MODEL = 'knox.AuthToken'
```

My slightly customized LoginView:

```py
class CustomLoginView(KnoxLoginView):
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print("Entered CustomLoginView.post()")  # Debugging line
        print("Request headers: ", request.META)  # Debugging line
        print("Request data: ", request.data)  # Debugging line

        response = super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)
        
        if response.status_code == 200:  # Código que indica sucesso
            print("Authentication succeeded. Redirecting...")  # Debugging line
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/bots/')  # Redirect
        else:
            print(f"Authentication failed with code {response.status_code}")  # Debugging line
            
        return response
```

The relevant section from the apps' urls.py:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('login/', CustomLoginView.as_view(), name='knox_login'),  
    path('logout/', knox_views.LogoutView.as_view(), name='knox_logout'),
    path('logoutall/', knox_views.LogoutAllView.as_view(), name='knox_logoutall'),
    re_path(r'api/auth/', include('knox.urls')),
]
```

Finally, the HTML from template:

```html
        <form id="loginForm">
          {% csrf_token %}
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="input-custom" id="username" name="username" required placeholder="Usuário">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="password" class="input-custom" id="password" name="password" required placeholder="Senha">
          </div>
          <button id="loginButton" type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-outline-secondary my-3">Entrar</button>
        </form>
```

And finally the JavaScript from this template:

```js
<script>
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    const loginForm = document.getElementById("loginForm");

    loginForm.addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      const username = document.getElementById("username").value;
      const password = document.getElementById("password").value;
      
      console.log("CSRF Token: ", csrfToken);

      fetch("{% url 'knox_login' %}", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          "X-CSRFToken": csrfToken
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ username, password })
      })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        if (data.token) {
          // Redirecionamento
          window.location.href = "{% url 'bots' %}";
        } else {
          // Error handling aqui
          alert("Credenciais inválidas");
        }
      });
    });
  });

  function getCookie(name) {
        let cookieValue = null;
        if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
            const cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
            for (let i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                const cookie = cookies[i].trim();
                if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                    cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return cookieValue;
    }

    const csrfToken = getCookie('csrftoken');
</script>
```

I'd appreciate any help with this!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use CustomLoginView you have to look in more detail at the tutorial provided by django rest knox there is a login method which is imported from 'from django.contrib.auth import login'

```
class CustomLoginView(KnoxLoginView):

    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print("Entered CustomLoginView.post()")  # Debugging line
        print("Request headers: ", request.META)  # Debugging line
        print("Request data: ", request.data)  # Debugging line
        serializer = LoginSerializer(data = request.data)
        if not serializer.is_valid():
            return Response({"message" : "Data is not match"}, status=400)
        email = serializer.data["email"]
        password = serializer.data["password"]
        user = User.objects.get(email = email)
        if user is None:
            return Response({"message" : "Cannot find user"})
        if not user.check_password(password):
            return Response({"message" : "Password not match"})

        login(request, user) # Importance

        response = super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)

        if response.status_code == 200:  # Código que indica sucesso
            print("Authentication succeeded. Redirecting...")  # Debugging line
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/bots/')  # Redirect
        else:
            print(f"Authentication failed with code {response.status_code}")  # Debugging line

        return response
```

Now your Token was Provided